# How to make firefox or google Chrome Add-on?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox-addon

I Want to make Firefox and Google Chrome Add-on in which language can i make? and how to make it in Firefox or Chrome compatible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Firefox the language is mostly JavaScript and XUL (**X**ML **U**I **L**anguage). Although it is possible to use Python and XUL, or even have compiled code bound trough XPCOM/XPconnect. But that's definitely not for beginners.

For Chrome the language is actually JavaScript, HTML and CSS. It's very similar to developing web application.

See tutorials:

- Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/building_an_extension
- Chrome: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html