# How to call a Windows application from google chrome and firefox?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I want to call a Windows (7/Vista/XP only) application from google chrome or Firefox. I am thinking of making an addon to do this. I can look up the tutorials mentioned here [How to make firefox or google Chrome Add-on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934635/how-to-make-firefox-or-google-chrome-add-on) . But, before that I wanted to know if it is possible to call a windows application from these browsers. Is it advisable to do such a thing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**On Chrome (Firefox also support npapi)**

you have NPAPI (c extension) to call os directly

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html

call `ShellExecuteEx` from npapi

**On Firefox**

you also have this to call os command

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProcess

Example from above url

```
// create an nsILocalFile for the executable
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                     .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath("c:\\myapp.exe");

// create an nsIProcess
var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
                        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
process.init(file);

// Run the process.
// If first param is true, calling thread will be blocked until
// called process terminates.
// Second and third params are used to pass command-line arguments
// to the process.
var args = ["argument1", "argument2"];
process.run(false, args, args.length);
```

Comment: The document says `NPAPI Plugin support for extension has been discontinued.`